# iTunes library access not consistent

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipad, appletv

I have an iPhone 4s, iPad2, and AppleTV3
My problem is that, my iTunes library on my PC doesn't consistently appear over all my devices (on my phone and ipad, I am referring to Apple's Remote app).  Sometimes, my itunes library will be visible by my apple TV and not my phone, or not my ipad, and vice versa. It's very random how some devices can see it and some cant. Even more strange, sometimes, a device will see it, and connect, and control it, but then shortly after, it's as if a connection is severed. And the device can no longer see my library. Any ideas why this would be? Here are some things to help you form answers.
- Everything is on the same network.
- They are all as up to date as possible.
- it DOES work, it just isn't always working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this problem.
When any devices can't find my itunes library, I close iTunes, and re-open it and it finds it right away.

I don't know why this is happening. I have every device on a dedicated router IP address. but at least I know that if the apple TV can't access my iTunes library, a quick restart of iTunes will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes have similar issues accessing iTunes libraries from AppleTVs. Sometimes I have better luck using a WiFi rather than Ethernet connection.

Also, have you tried assigning your AppleTVs static IP addresses (assuming you use DHCP?)

Comment: I'm using everything wirelessly actually. And no I haven't tried the static IP. I was debating going into my router settings, and dedicating specific IP addresses to all my devices. Is that something that might make sense to do?

Comment: You can set the DHCP pool in your router settings to say 192.168.1.32 - 192.168.1.255 - these are addresses which can be handed out dynamically using its DHCP service (assuming that they all begin with 192.168.1.x on your network). You can then just assign static IP addresses to devices which need them, outside of the range of the DHCP pool, i.e. any addresses in the range 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.31